# What is the difference between angular 2 and @angular inputs?

Tags: angularjs, angular

**What is the difference between imports from angular2 and @angular?**

I have found some of the boilerplate using [angular 2/core] and [@angular/core]

I am curious is there are any differences or if I should just rename the angular 2 folder.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer this because I better understand this question. What you are referring to is code that looks like this

```
import {Component} from '@angular.core'
```

`@angular` is used for RC (Release Candidate) versions, whereas `angular2` is used for beta versions

In the RC, `angular2/core` becomes `@angular/core.`

The SystemJS configuration is different since you don't have bundled JS files.

Comment: Thanks Richard.

Now i know the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 is entirely component based. Controllers and $scope are no longer used. They have been replaced by components and directives.

Directives can also be used in components, this applies both to its own directives as predefined directives.

[Source](https://dzone.com/articles/typed-front-end-with-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks MatHatrik,

I am not talking about angular one and angular two.

i am talking about angular two both are angular two but some buddy use angular2/core and some buddy use @angular/core

So is there any difference in both of them or just renaming of folder.

Comment: @Tamesh, sorry mate , miss read your question :)

Comment: No problem, it happens sometime